# How to get the access to the id from my element?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I'm trying to learn to use `class`.
And I have a `class` that creates a `div element` for me.
Which got an id.
And, I have a function that overrides the `id`, but how do I do that?

My Class:

```
var count = 0;
class Element {
  constructor(width,height,into) {
      this.createElement("",into,width,height)
    }
    createElement(type,into,width,height) {
      if (!type)
        type = "div"

      let element = document.createElement(type);
      element.style.width = width;
      element.style.height = height;
      element.style.border = 1+"px solid"
      element.style.position = "relative";
      element.name = "element" + count;

      document.querySelector(into).append(element)
      count ++
    }
    addID(name,clasName) {
      clasName = clasName.id
      return document.querySelector(`.+${clasName}`) = this.name
    }
}
```

My Script:

```
var test = new Element(100 + "%", 100 + "px", "body");
  test.addID("MainDiv", test.id)
```

Thx for u help

Comment: You're creating element but not assigning any class or id to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `this.className = className.id;`. The question is a bit vague but the `this` keyword will give you a reference to your class instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Problems & solution:**

1. Element Class not return `id` .So `test.id` is undefined one.So you must declare with `this.id` for Better understand in class refer [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)
2. Add embedded the id with element using `element.id=this.id` in createElement function
3. And document.querySelector target classname selector.But if you are passing `id` use with `#` instead of `.`
4. And return statement in `addID` is not working .Because You are passing the value to element .Use `textContent` for pass value to `div`

```js
var count = 0;
class Element {
  constructor(width,height,into) {
      this.createElement("",into,width,height)
      this.id='one';
      this.name="is this name"
    }
    createElement(type,into,width,height) {
      if (!type)
        type = "div"

      let element = document.createElement(type);
      element.style.width = width;
      element.style.height = height;
      element.style.border = 1+"px solid"
      element.style.position = "relative";
      element.name = "element" + count;
      element.id=this.id;

      document.querySelector(into).append(element)
      count ++
    }
    addID(name,clasName) {
      clasName = clasName.id;
      document.querySelector(`#${clasName}`).textContent = name
    }
}

var test = new Element(100 + "%", 100 + "px", "body");
  test.addID("MainDiv", test.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

first of all I had to use the referrer `this.`!
For adding or removing classnames or id, you also can manipulate your `created element` in progress.

```
'use strict'

var count = 0;
class Element {
  constructor(type, width, height, into, functionName, value) {
    if (into)
      this.createElement(type, into, width, height, functionName, value)
  }
  createElement(type, into, width, height, functionName, value) {
    if (!type)
      type = "div"

    this.element = document.createElement(type);
    this.element.style.width = width;
    this.element.style.height = height;
    this.element.style.border = 1 + "px solid"
    this.element.style.position = "relative";
    // this.element.id = this.id
    if (type == "button")
      this.extendButton(this.element, functionName, value);

    document.querySelector(into).append(this.element);
    count++;
  }

  extendButton(element, functionName, value) {
    this.element.onclick = functionName;
    this.element.innerHTML = value;
  }

  addID(name, clasName) {
    return this.element.id = name
  }

} //END
```

Script:

```
  var test = new Element("",100 + "%", 100 + "px", "body");
  test.addID("try");
  test.addID("MainDiv")

  var test2 = new Element("",80 + "%", 80 + "px", "#MainDiv");
  test2.addID("harry");
  var buttonTest = new Element("button","","","#MainDiv","showOutgoings","testet")
```

Guys thank you for your suggestion =)